# Applied Uses for Pure Theorems ("Mathematical Sinners")

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, number-theory, set-theory

As part of a project I will be keeping ongoing indefinitely after a suggestion from a teacher of mine, I wish to introduce *Mathematical Sinners*. The goal is to find physical applications or descriptions of physical phenomena using what would be considered highly "pure" theorems (i.e. from number theory, or abstract algebra or something). A great example would be if someone could find a "use" for the existence of Khinchine's Constant.

Can you think of any?

Comment: Would the hairy ball theorem and the consequence that there is at, at any time, at least one place on earth with no wind be the kind of thing you're looking for?

Comment: That would be one example - I hope for many people to chime in with their own ideas for such things! Diversity is the key thing here (finding uses across mathematics). The uses don't have to be amazingly practical, however.

Comment: @Arthur : perhaps you could write out a full answer ?. all : perhaps this should be community wiki ?

Comment: @Max : I think that a community wiki is exactly what I would be looking for.

Comment: I would expect  an obvious example would be the use of various basic results  of number theory in  computerized crytography.

Answer (score 1):

In 1951, John Nash published a [paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1969529?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) in Annals of Mathematics proving the existence of a solution concept for finite, non-cooperative games he termed 'equilibrium points,' that has gone on to bear his name (the so-called 'Nash equilibrium' solution concept of game theory).

His 1951 existence proof makes direct use of the [Brouwer fixed point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem), a piece of machinery usually derived as a consequence of some of easy properties of [singular homology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_homology).

Comment: Decades ago there was a Scientific American article on research into some causes of heart fibrillation, in which an explanation of the cause was Brouwer's Fixed Point Theorem. I am sorry I cannot recall any details that help to search for this article or other references.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I'd actually be fascinated to read that as an application.

Comment: It was so long ago. I barely remember it so I can't give  any  details.